# c++ builder: getting values via ADOQuery using SELECT

Tags: sql-server, delphi, ado, c++builder

The question is as for delphi coders as for c++ builder coders, cuz I'm using the same components.
I'm trying to fill labels on the form by the data from database. I do a SELECT query via TADOQuery. But when I try to get a result, I always get an error like "ADOQuery1: Field 'count' not found".
'id' passed to the function is an autoincrement field value, which is EXACTLY exists in database (it was got via DBLookupComboBox). Also, executing the query manually to show result in DBGrid is successfull.
Querying without parameters and writing 'id' value to query string fails too.
What's the problem? Here's the code.

```
void TSellForm::LoadData(int id) {
    TADOQuery* q = DataModule1->ADOQuery1;
    q->Active = false;
    try
    {
        q->SQL->Text = "select * from drugs where(id=:id)";
        q->Parameters->ParamByName("id")->Value = IntToStr(id);
        q->ExecSQL();
        this->LabelAvail->Caption = q->FieldByName("count")->Value;
    }
    catch (Exception* e) {
        MessageBox(NULL, PChar(WideString(e->Message)),
            L"Exception", MB_OK|MB_ICONWARNING);
    }
    q->SQL->Clear();
}
```

Comment: I'm confused. Are you having two separate issues? As for the "field count not found", are you sure this field is in your database? We cannot see your database structure.

Comment: COUNT is a reserved word in SQL, so you might need to pass it with "": q->fieldByName("\"Count\"")->Value; I don't know if the ID could be the same issue. Another thing to check is the ADOQuery1 component, maybe you have FieldDefs around that don't include those fields?

Comment: Also, have you tried doing "q->Active = true" instead of ExecSQL? IIRC ExecSQL is used for queries that don't return a dataset (for instance, UPDATE, DELETE, etc)

Comment: @RodrigoGómez ID isn't reserved, I use it all the time in SQL Server/ADO.

Comment: Thanks! Simply using q->Active instead of ExecSQL() helped me. I still can't believe that single property change does all the hard work o_O

Comment: @Str1ker It's just the way it's designed to work. Glad it worked with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ExecSQL` is only used for SQL statements that don't return a recordset, and to determine the results you use `RowsAffected`.

For `SELECT` statements (which return a recordset), you use `Open` or set `Active` to true.

Also, `count` is a reserved word in most SQL dialects (as in `SELECT Count(*) FROM ...`, so if you have a column with that name you're going to need to escape it, typically by using either `[]` or double-quotes around it or by aliasing it in the `SELECT` itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
ADOQuery1->Close();
ADOQuery1->SQL->Text= "SELECT * FROM reportTble WHERE (firstName =:firstName) " ;
ADOQuery1->Parameters->ParamByName("firstName")->Value =  textBox->Text ;
ADOQuery1->Open();
```

This is how you can use `ADOQuery`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.